# Hive external table definition for a text file with multi-line records

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I need to parse this file into a hive Table which is a dataset of movie reviews from amazon. I´m having problems constructing the regular expression to parse the .txt file and create the table with the correct column type.

The .txt

```
product/productId: B0001G6PZC
review/userId: A3F3THLLZXURQN
review/profileName: A. Y
review/helpfulness: 3/3
review/score: 4.0
review/time: 1199664000
review/summary: Good story, Good action. Good Drama. Good Movie
review/text: When I first heard of this movie, I didn't think it would be that great, so I never bothered to go see it in theaters. Later on, I ended up downloading the movie, and didn't think much of it.<br /><br />But now after watching the movie on BD, I think that the movie is quite outstanding. Its got a good story behind it, with some level of historical basis behind it with Samurai becoming phased out into Japan's modernization.<br /><br />It does a good job in immersing you into the conflicts that warriors must endure... and yet, find peace with the way of the Samurai as they are a warrior race and not savages.<br /><br />4/5 stars.

product/productId: B0001G6PZC
review/userId: A3J78KAIPW6KAH
review/profileName: Joan Paolo De Bastos "conde_almasy"
review/helpfulness: 3/3
review/score: 4.0
review/time: 1198540800
review/summary: Good Movie. Wonderful Visuals. A Great Way to SHOW OFF you Hi-Def System
review/text: Last Samurai is no masterpiece<br /><br />but technically it is<br /><br />the visuals, the sound effects, the music.<br /><br />If you want to show off to your friends what a great hi-def system you got, purchase this movie.<br /><br />If you want a classic, but lord of the rings or gone with the wind instead.

product/productId: B0001G6PZC
review/userId: A3F3B6HY9RJI04
review/profileName: James Duckett
review/helpfulness: 3/3
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1192060800
review/summary: Great Movie, Fantastic HD Quality
review/text: After picking up my HD DVD player I've had troubles watching regular DVD movies.  I had heard some good things about this movie but couldn't pass it up once it was in high definition.<br /><br />The story is pretty good.  This is the story of Captain Algren who has been sent to Japan in the late 1800's in order to help them modernize the Japanese army as they go from fighting with swords and arrows to machine guns and cannons.<br /><br />After the "modern" Japanese army prematurely attacks the Samurai and lose horribly, Captain Algren is taken captive by the Samurai and introduced to their way of life and refusal to lay down the sword in the name of compliance.  In time, Captain Algren finds himself wanting to become one of the Samurai and learning more of their way of life.<br /><br />The story is pretty good but what raises this up to the level of being outstanding is the high definition quality of the movie.  It was fantastic, especially seeing the colorful Japanese landscape in all of its magnificence.<br /><br />If you like Tom Cruise action movies, this is one to pick up especially in high definition (whether it be Blu-Ray or HD DVD).  The violence can be extremely graphic (hey, this is war) so if you are sensitive to that you may want to look for something else.  Otherwise, the pacing of the movie is pretty good.  It isn't an all out gore-fest... there is action and then it breaks and lets you relax and catch up a little bit and then goes back to action and so on and so forth.
```

This is my SQL :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE movies(id string, uId string, profileName string, helpfulness string, score float, time int, summary string, text string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH serdeproperties( "input.regex" = "[ ].*", "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s"")
location '/user/hduser/moviesTest';
```

However hive is not parsing it correctly and: `SELECT * FROM movies` gives me this result:

```
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Can anyone tell me what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: The fields of the table  has to be a continuous string but in this case each of the fields starts in a new line so hive tries to get all the fields in a single line resulting in NULL rows...... If all the fields were put together in a line then the regular expression has to changed......

Comment: Can I change the regular expression without having to put all the data in a single line??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily do by Hive UDF;

your data is in table suppose temp with single column named as line;

```
create table temp(line String);
load data local inpath 'review.txt' into table temp;
select line from temp;

roduct/productId: B0001G6PZC
review/userId: A3F3THLLZXURQN
review/profileName: A. Y
review/helpfulness: 3/3

review/score: 4.0
review/time: 1199664000
review/summary: Good story, Good action. Good Drama. Good Movie
review/text: When I first heard of this movie, I didn't think it would be that great, so I never bothered to go see it in theaters. Later on, I ended up downloading the movie, and didn't think much of it.<br /><br />But now after watching the movie on BD, I think that the movie is quite outstanding. Its got a good story behind it, with some level of historical basis behind it with Samurai becoming phased out into Japan's modernization.<br /><br />It does a good job in immersing you into the conflicts that warriors must endure... and yet, find peace with the way of the Samurai as they are a warrior race and not savages.<br /><br />4/5 stars.

product/productId: B0001G6PZC
review/userId: A3J78KAIPW6KAH
review/profileName: Joan Paolo De Bastos "conde_almasy"
review/helpfulness: 3/3
review/score: 4.0
review/time: 1198540800
............

............
```

Create a Hive Udf in java. source is here

```
package HiveUDF;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

public class ReviewDataUdf extends UDF {
    String s = " ";
    String structuredFormat;
    int inds = 0;
    int inde = 0;

    public String evaluate(String t) {
        s = s + " " + t;
        if (t.contains("review/text:")) {
            String productId = "";
            try {
                if (s.contains("product/productId:")) {
                    inds = s.indexOf("product/productId:");
                    inde = s.indexOf("review/userId:", inds);
                    productId = s.substring(inds + 18, inde);
                } else {
                    productId = "N/A";
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                productId = "";
            }
            String userId = "";
            try {
                if (s.contains("review/userId:")) {

                    inds = s.indexOf("review/userId:");
                    inde = s.indexOf("review/profileName:", inds);
                    userId = s.substring(inds + 14, inde);
                } else {
                    userId = "N/A";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                userId = "";
            }

            String profileName = "";
            try {
                if (s.contains("review/profileName:")) {
                    inds = s.indexOf("review/profileName:");
                    inde = s.indexOf("review/helpfulness:", inds);
                    profileName = s.substring(inds + 19, inde);
                } else {
                    profileName = "N/A";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                profileName = "";
            }

            String helpfulness = "";
            try {
                if (s.contains("review/helpfulness:")) {
                    inds = s.indexOf("review/helpfulness:");
                    inde = s.indexOf("review/score:", inds);
                    helpfulness = s.substring(inds + 20, inde);
                } else {
                    helpfulness = "N/A";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                helpfulness = "";
            }

            String score = "";
            try {
                if (s.contains("review/score:")) {
                    inds = s.indexOf("review/score:");
                    inde = s.indexOf("review/time:", inds);
                    score = s.substring(inds + 14, inde);
                } else {
                    score = "N/A";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                score = "";
            }

            String time = "";
            try {
                if (s.contains("review/time:")) {
                    inds = s.indexOf("review/time:");
                    inde = s.indexOf("review/summary:", inds);
                    time = s.substring(inds + 14, inde);
                } else {
                    time = "N/A";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                time = "";
            }

            String summary = "";
            try {
                if (s.contains("review/summary:")) {
                    inds = s.indexOf("review/summary:");
                    inde = s.indexOf("review/text:", inds);
                    summary = s.substring(inds + 16, inde);
                } else {
                    summary = "N/A";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                summary = "";
            }

            String text = "";
            try {
                if (s.contains("review/text:")) {
                    inds = s.indexOf("review/text:");
                    inde = s.indexOf(s.length(), inds);
                    text = s.substring(inds + 14);
                } else {
                    text = "N/A";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                text = "";
            }
            structuredFormat = productId + "\t" + userId + "\t" + profileName + "\t" + helpfulness + "\t" + score
                    + "\t" + time + "\t" + summary + "\t" + text;
            s = "";
            return structuredFormat.trim();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

export ReviewDataUdf.jar, Register it in hive and create function.

```
hive> ADD JAR /home/Kishore/ReviewDataUdf.jar;

hive> create temporary FUNCTION structReview as 'HiveUDF.ReviewDataUdf';
```

use structReview function to get structured data.

```
Create table AmazonReview as
select split(review,"\t")[0] as productId, split(review,"\t")[1] as userId, split(review,"\t")[2] as profileName,split(review,"\t")[3] as helpfulness, split(review,"\t")[4] as score,split(review,"\t")[5] as time,split(review,"\t")[6] as summary,split(review,"\t")[7] as text from(
select structReview(line) As review from temp ) b
where review != "NULL";
```

data is in structured format in table AmazonReview

```
select productId, userId, profileName from AmazonReview;
OK
B0001G6PZC   A3F3THLLZXURQN      A. Y 
B0001G6PZC   A3J78KAIPW6KAH      Joan Paolo De Bastos "conde_almasy" 
B0001G6PZC   A3F3B6HY9RJI04      James Duckett
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Before doing anything above, I have to put the .txt file in a table? What do I use as delimitators when loading the data?

Comment: Hello again. I was wondering if it´s possible to specify the data types when doing this type of data extraction. For example give a float data type to the score column?